# Confused about the two extra buttons on the Cyborg R.A.T. 5

Tags: mouse, gaming

I got a RAT 5 today and it's working fine now. But there are two extra buttons I'm a little confused about. One is the one which switches profiles, and the other is by the scroll wheel and says "DPI" on it.

1) Is there an easier way to see which mode you're in? The mode switch button is positioned such that my eyes don't meet it, and I have to move my head right over the mouse to see it. There are lights on the underside of that button, which I can see perfectly well; what do these mean? And is there a way to get them to reflect the mode you're in?

2) What does the DPI button do? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. I've found that I can see the color of the light on my finger.  I don't think there's a better way.
2. There are 4 modes (indicated by the 4 red led's on the left side (just above the red button).  The DPI button is actually 2 buttons; notice that if you push up on the button, more lights will turn on and vice versa for the bottom half.  You can customize the cursor speed of the 4 modes.  DPI stands for dots per inch, and is a measure of mouse sensitivity.